# Check if there is a schema named bla and if not create one

Tags: t-sql, object, database-schema

How can I check if there is a schema named bla? I want something like

```
if object_id(bla) is null
begin
 create SCHEMA EHS AUTHORIZATION dbo;
end
```

I know that I could use object_schema_name but that takes an int as an input. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping with the same type of idiom.

```
IF Schema_id('Bla') IS NULL 
  BEGIN 
      EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA bla AUTHORIZATION dbo;') 
  END
```

You could also do an `EXISTS` check against [`sys.schemas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176011.aspx)

IIRC `CREATE SCHEMA` has to be in its own batch hence use of `EXEC`.